# What is wrong with this code (Basic C++ Code)

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ programming language. I have made a file which contains a Class and shows an output "Hello World" to users like this:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class print()
{
    public:
        print(string name)
        {
            setName(name);
        }
        void setName(string name)
        {
            output = name;
        }
        string getName()
        {
            return output;
        }
    private:
        string output;
};

int main()
{
    print print1("Hello");
    print print2("World");

    cout << "Output1 is " << print1.getName() << "Output2 is " << print2.getName() << endl;
    return 0;
}﻿
```

It looks fine but I get this error message:

**||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|**

So what does this mean, is there any mistake in the code ?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Also you are missing `using std::string;`

Comment: There's a U+FEFF at the end of your program. That trips up my compiler for example. You'll probably get better error diagnostics if you remove it.

Comment: Avoid `using` , in your case it just makes your code unclear. Writing `std::string` instead of `string` will make your code much more readable.

Comment: Change `void setName(string name)`  to `void setName(const std::string& name)` to save copying strings. Use the same pattern in the constructor.

Comment: And **compile on the command line with all warnings and debug info**, e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g yoursource.cc -o yourprog` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Your error message is not given by your compiler (but by a misconfigured IDE)

Comment: Change `string getName()` to `std::string getName()  const` as it does not change the object

Comment: @wrai please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```
class print()    // <-- class declaration doesn't take parentheses

print(string name)    // <-- you have to use std::string
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as some other people already pointed out, there's some errors in your code (I won't repeat here). But that's not the major problem, it seems that you don't even get so far that these errors show up:

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
```

seems to tell that there's something really wrong with your build environment and you don't compile/build at all. It seems that you have not setup a project/makefile properly. Please familiarize yourself with your compiler, linker and the makefiles or projects necessary to build your program.

Perhaps, if you use an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) like QDevelop, Eclipse or KDevelop, you will have to tell your IDE what to do somewhere in the "project settings" (or similar) dialog of the IDE.

I'd search for a simple howto/example/tutorial how to build a file with your tools properly (there's plenty of help for any compiler and IDE on google). The easiest thing would be, if you find an already set up project, which you can legally change for your purposes.

Once you have done that and compile, you will get some nice and detailed error messages about the errors in your code and you will be easily able to fix them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First : instead of using multiple `using std::` make it `using namespace std;` but if you like it multiple eating your time and lines add `using std::string;`

Second : class declaration doesn't take parentheses it will be

```
class print 
{
    //class code
};
```

Third : 
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|

means that you have problems in your compiler whether is g++ Intel or whatever other compiler you use fix => reinstall your compiler.

Fourth note for you : not only focus on the normal `/*your writing*/` code errors it could be in declarations such as what happened here.